# my java code won't redirect - ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

Tags: java, google-chrome, intellij-idea

i'm struggling for another hour to fix something and i can't get it to work:

I have a simple program that takes the information from an registration form inside index.html and adds it to the postgreSQL database.

When i hit sign up, the program works and adds the info in the database

The problem is i can't get the redirect to work

i get the following error

```
This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:8081/register might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT
```

My java code is as following:

- This is the RegistrationController class

```
package ro.fortech.guardianangel.registration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public RedirectView registerSubmit(Users users) {
        Users user = userRepository.save(users);
        return new RedirectView("file:///C:/Users/timis/Desktop/programare/curs%20java/Proiect/frontend/index.html#!");
    }
}
```

- This is the Users class

```
package ro.fortech.guardianangel.registration;

import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

- And this is the UserRepository interface

```
package ro.fortech.guardianangel.registration;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Integer> {}
```

So basically after i hit submit i want my browser to take me back to:

```
file:///C:/Users/timis/Desktop/programare/curs%20java/Proiect/frontend/index.html
```

Comment: [redirecting from http:// to file:// was not supported in the last decade at least](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18685/are-there-any-know-browsers-that-support-file-url-redirection) due to security concerns. Can you put the contents of the file onto some http server instead?

Comment: @teapot418 you can add this as an answer and ill vote it as an winner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reasonable web browser will reject attempts to redirect from an `http://` URL to a `file://` one. This is for security reasons and was the case for a long time, see also:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18685/are-there-any-know-browsers-that-support-file-url-redirection

You have to put the contents of that file on to some web server and redirect to that.